# webdriver with c# - How do I iterate around an option drop down menu?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following drop down menu / list.  What I would like to do is to be able to iterate around each drop down item, click on it, then verify that it's been selected.  Below I have provide sample code for just 3 items from the drop down

```
<div id="rtList"><span class="rt-combobox"><input name="" type="text" autocomplete="off" label="" placeholder="" class=""><span class="rt-combobox-button" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">?</span><div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none; left: 342px; top: 0px; display: none;">

<div class="goog-menuitem" role="menuitem" id=":7" aria-hidden="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="menuitem-content">List item number 1</div></div>

<div class="goog-menuitem" role="menuitem" id=":8" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="menuitem-content">List item number 2</div></div>

<div class="goog-menuitem" role="menuitem" id=":9" aria-hidden="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="menuitem-content">List item number 3</div></div>

</div></span></div>
```

Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated as always

Thanks

*******************  EDIT *******************************

I have it working now.  Here is what I'm using:

```
IWebElement parent = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("rtlist"));
parent.Click();

foreach (IWebElement child in parent.FindElements(By.ClassName("menuitem-content")))
{
child.Click();
parent.Click();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code for clicking all the menu items.

```
IWebElement parent = ie.FindElement(By.Id("rtList"));
foreach (IWebElement child in parent.FindElements(By.ClassName("menuitem-content")))
{
    child.Click();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for helping.  Your code works to a certain degree in that it will click the first item in the drop down list but it doesn't continue to click through the remaining items in the drop down

Comment: Just wanted to update you that you can't select drop down items in the list more than one, unless it has Multiple Select property set to True. The above code works only when the mentioned property is set to true.

Comment: Hi.  I have it working fine now.  It wont click onto the next list item but if I click back onto the drop down menu it works fine

            }

Answer (score 0):

Using "SelectElement" class you can select any options easily if you don't have to click.

```
var selectElement= new SelectElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("rtList")));
var optionCount = selectElement.Options.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < optionCount; i++)
{
    selectElement.SelectByIndex(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Appreciate it